# PromQL-Query for used heap size after full GC

Tags: jvm, prometheus, heap-memory, promql

I'm currently looking for a query that would return the used heap-size after a full GC run occurred.

The goal is to suggest a *calculated* value for the `-XmxN` parameter, based on the return-value I am looking for.

I know of the following queries:

```
1. jvm_memory_usage_after_gc_percent
2. jvm_gc_memory_allocated_bytes_total
```

AFAIK

1. only returns the percentage of the long-lived heap
2. would return an increment for the increase of the young generation

Is it just a matter of adding those numbers together (while doing the necessary conversion), to get to my desired value of the used heap after a full GC?
Or is there a different approach, maybe to get a timestamp of the last full GC?